# Internet speed required to use Microsoft Teams from Japan to the USA

Tags: internet, network-speed, microsoft-teams

I really hope this is the right place to ask (this is my first question here so please go easy).
I have a great opportunity to go to work remotely (HR signed off on it) from Japan. I have a place to stay (free and everything)!

The Problem: The place I can stay at for free has SLOW internet. It is listed here: https://isp.today/en/o/FLETS-ADSL,o-12402

Specifically the:
47 Mbit/s DOWN
5 Mbit/s UP
option

I will need to do a teams call everyday (daily scrum call) No video is required... however, I am not sure if this Internet speed is fast enough. I HIGHLY doubt it. However, I am hoping someone here can tell me otherwise (if not, I will have to turn the offer down)

I have no clue what the ping would be, though I am guessing very long. To make things worse, the location that I need to call to everyday would be Boston MA, USA.

If anyone could give me a bit of in-sight into if these speeds can do what I need them too, I would really appreciate it!

Other than that my work just requires me to code a bit and these speeds should be fine for GIT (though still a bit slow)

Comment: Voice traffic requires _very_ little bandwidth.  Typical VoLTE calls allocate around 30kbps for the dedicated voice bearers.  The venerable old 1.5 Mbps T1 was actually 24 56k (+8kbps signalling) voice channels multiplexed together.  Latency will be your main concern - i.e. it will be at least a quarter to half a second from the time you start talking until the rest of the participants hear you (and vice versa).  On one-on-one calls this isn't usually a problem, but on group calls it can get annoying (I live in eastern Europe but am on MS Teams calls to my US employer many times a day)

Comment: One other bit of semi-related advice:  Assuming your employer frowns upon using the company VPN for personal use (or you just don't care to have them logging your private activity), start researching VPNs as soon as you get there -- take advantage of the free trials to see which offer the best bandwidth using YOUR connection, aren't detected by services you may want to use in the US (for example: Netflix is very loose about VPNs, Amazon Prime not so much), etc.  I even had trouble paying a particular credit card bill from a non-US IP address . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 47 Mbit/s DOWN 5 Mbit/s UP is/would be considered good internet anywhere in the world.
2. Latency, rather than bandwidth, is probably a more important factor to consider.
3. Microsoft publishes Teams bandwidth requirements at the link below:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/prepare-network#bandwidth-requirements

If the latency is reasonable, the bandwidth is more than sufficient.

Comment: There's also official MS 365 speed test site [here](https://connectivity.office.com/), probably want to try to check it too.

Answer (score 1):

Up until late last year I was routinely doing a weekly call from Sydney (Aus) to Hyderabad (india) and I was on an 11/1Mbps connection. Calls included screen share and occasional video. It was fine. The distance is similar as the crow flies but not so sure about where the actual cables run.

Answer (score 1):

This is the third answer encouraging you to go for it. I used to have 8MB down, 1MB up and had regular Skype calls from Japan to my family in Europe. Including occasional video calls. Delays in the conversation can't be ignored, but if everybody cooperates, there is no problem to deal with it. Welcome to Japan!